# Sharepoint active feature "Workflows can use app permissions" failed

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow

In Sharepoint 2013, I'm going to active feature "Workflows can use app permissions" to start my workflow according to this [article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112631/setting-permissions-in-sharepoint-2013-workflow) (pic 1).

However, when I active the feature, it shows the error(pic 2).

Anyone here can explain what the error is? And how to solve the problem?

[image]
Pic 1.

[image]
Pic 2.

Answer (score 0):

When you open sharepoint designer and try to create new workflow, do you have "Sharepoint 2013 Workflow" option?
If no - check if you have installed and configured workflow manager:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx#section4